# Marshaling and/or saving Objects with/without their current state to file and reloading them in Python

Tags: python, marshalling, saving-data

Hi 
Is there any known method, through API or clean programming practice to save an object to a file and then load the object again for instance  if: Object inst is an instance of class C
and it has variables V1 and V2 which are currently initialized, can we save it to a file and read it back?  Now what if we want to take this further, what is we have a processes or a thread running can we save it and resurrect it again?

Comment: Have a look at the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module or the (slightly) higher-level [Shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) module

Comment: @rob-cowie  @sven-marnach  Thanks Any examples?

Comment: @Max: there are examples at the bottom of each of the module doc pages. PyMOTW has also covered them both at http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pickle/index.html and http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/shelve/

Comment: @rob-cowie Thanks again :P I am noob so you must forgive the noob requests!

Comment: @Max: No problem. Word of caution though; I've never come across a reason to pickle objects. It is certainly a legitimate thing to do in some situations, but make sure you know why you are saving the _objects_ and not your _state_ (your data).

Comment: @Max: Don't forget to accept the answer if you feel it helped :)